# Prepared Statement in Function

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a prepared statement that will insert an entry into the database. The statement works fine and inserts entries. I wrap the statement in a function, call the function, and it no longer inserts into the database. Is there an issue with calling these statements from a function? Side note...my end goal is to actually put this function in a class as a method. I was attempting that, and began troubleshooting and have determined the error begins when putting in a function. My next step is to move this into a class. Is there anything else in my code that would prevent that from being possible?

```
<?php

include 'main_connection.php';

function add() {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$name);
    $name = "test";
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

}

add();  

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issue. Specifically, `add()` does not know the variables `$mysqli` or `$name`.

There are numerous ways to solve this. A *quick* suggestion would be to pass parameters to `add()`:

```
function add($mysqli, $name) {
  // your code
}

add($mysqli, $name);
```

Or to use the global scope:

```
function add() {
  global $mysqli, $name;
  // your code
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I am not advocating either. Reference the following - [PHP global in functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions)

Comment: Can I correct this by calling class new mysqli INSIDE the function..and is this a good idea?

Comment: You could. But I don't think that is a good idea if you have already made the connection.

Answer (score 1):

```
function add($mysqli, $name) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$name);
    $name = "test";
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

}

add($mysqli, $name);
```